# Codeigniter query two same tables

Tags: codeigniter

I have two tables in one database. 
One table can be filled by the customers and one by us. The two tables has the same columns. How can i get data from two tables in one foreach?

I have tblexample and tbluserexample.

This is my current get function:

```
  public function get($id = '', $where = array())
{
    $this->db->select('*,tblexample.id as exampleid');
    $this->db->from('tblexample');
    $this->db->where($where);

    if (is_numeric($id)) {
    $this->db->where('tblexample.id', $id);
    $example = $this->db->get()->row();
    if ($example) {
        $example->attachment            = '';
        $example->filetype              = '';
        $example->attachment_added_from = 0;

        $this->db->where('rel_id', $id);
        $this->db->where('rel_type', 'example');
        $file = $this->db->get('tblfiles')->row();

        if ($file) {
            $example->attachment            = $file->file_name;
            $example->filetype              = $file->filetype;
            $example->attachment_added_from = $file->staffid;
        }
    }

    return $example;
      }
     return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Best regards,
Jaron

Comment: what you have tried??

Answer (score 1):

is there any field common then just join two tables .. if not then merge two arrays (query results) into one using array_merge().

take 1st query to array1 & 2nd to array2 then merge and return array2

```
$array2=array_merge($array2, $array1);
```